# Secure "auto_route" routes using "flutter_bloc"

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

Please anyone suggest a way to secure "auto_route" routes using "flutter_bloc".
In the above example My bloc state has been changed i.e. "authenticated" (Center text has been change to authenticated) But auth_guard never push route. Anyone help.

**app_widget.dart**

```
class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  AppWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final _appRouter = getIt<AppRouter>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      routerDelegate: _appRouter.delegate(),
      routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(),
      builder: (context, child) => BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => getIt<UserAuthenticationBloc>(),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**user_authentication_page.dart**

```
class UserAuthenticationPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserAuthenticationPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<UserAuthenticationBloc, UserAuthenticationState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        state.maybeMap(
          orElse: () => null,
          authenticated: (_) => context.router.push<bool>(const HomeRoute()),
        );
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return BlocBuilder<UserAuthenticationBloc, UserAuthenticationState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Center(
                    child: Text(
                      state.map(
                        authenticated: (_) => "authenticated",
                        unAuthenticated: (_) => "unAuthenticated",
                        loading: (_) => "loading",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.maxFinite,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 24.0),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () => context
                              .read<UserAuthenticationBloc>()
                              .add(
                                  const UserAuthenticationEvent.requestLogin()),
                          child: const Text('Get Started'),
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                              (_) => const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(8.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  if (state == const UserAuthenticationState.loading()) ...[
                    SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01),
                    const LinearProgressIndicator(value: null),
                  ],
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**user_authentication_bloc.dart**

```
@injectable
class UserAuthenticationBloc
    extends Bloc<UserAuthenticationEvent, UserAuthenticationState> {
  UserAuthenticationBloc(this._userAuthenticationRepository)
      : super(
          const UserAuthenticationState.unAuthenticated(),
        ) {
    on<_RequestLogin>(_requestLogin);
  }

  final IUserAuthenticationRepository _userAuthenticationRepository;

  void _requestLogin(
      _RequestLogin event, Emitter<UserAuthenticationState> emit) async {
    emit(const UserAuthenticationState.loading());
    return emit(await _userAuthenticationRepository
        .redirectToLogin()
        .then(
          (value) => value.fold(
            (l) => const UserAuthenticationState.unAuthenticated(),
            (r) => const UserAuthenticationState.authenticated(),
          ),
        )
        .catchError((_) => const UserAuthenticationState.unAuthenticated()));
  }
}
```

**router.dart**

```
@MaterialAutoRouter(
  replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route',
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
    AutoRoute(
      path: '/login',
      page: UserAuthenticationPage,
    ),
    AutoRoute(
      path: '/',
      page: HomePage,
      guards: [AuthGuard],
      children: [
        AutoRoute(
          path: 'dashboard',
          name: 'dashboardRouter',
          page: EmptyRouterPage,
          children: [
            AutoRoute(
              path: '',
              page: DashboardPage,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        AutoRoute(
          path: 'notifications',
          name: 'notificationRouter',
          page: EmptyRouterPage,
          children: [
            AutoRoute(
              path: '',
              page: NotificationPage,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        AutoRoute(
          path: 'settings',
          name: 'settingsRouter',
          page: EmptyRouterPage,
          children: [
            AutoRoute(
              path: '',
              page: SettingsPage,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    )
  ],
)
class $AppRouter {}
```

**auth_guard.dart**

```
@injectable
class AuthGuard extends AutoRouteGuard {
  final UserAuthenticationBloc userAuthenticationBloc;

  AuthGuard(this.userAuthenticationBloc);

  @override
  void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) {
    userAuthenticationBloc.state.map(
      loading: (_) => null,
      unAuthenticated: (_) => router.push(const UserAuthenticationRoute()),
      authenticated: (_) => resolver.next(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't navigate is because it is not getting the latest updated state. In order to get that you would have to listen to the state stream.

```
    @override
void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) {
  userAuthenticationBloc.stream.listen((state) {
    if (state is authenticated && !resolver.isResolved) {
      // TODO: ROUTE TO THE PAGE YOU WANT TO GO TO

     resolver.next(true);
    }
  },);
}
```